# A process serving application pool 'PleskControlPanel' terminated unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7.5, plesk

I've rented a VDS and it has plesk 10 installed for 10 domains. Running on Windows server and IIS 7.5. I've defined web site which is not actualy in plesk panel but it has DNS record and file at Plesk DNS (under C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\dns var & etc folders).

IIS is producing warning messages like:

**A process serving application pool 'PleskControlPanel' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3384'. The process exit code was '0xc0000374'.**

Message is produced after application pool is shut down after 30 minutes of inactivity. I don't remember if the messages were produced before DNS modification.

Can anybody tell me if it is wrong to manually modify plesk DNS files and if yes how can I publish web sites outside Plesk?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few workarounds suggested here: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=88554
I'm sorry I cannot offer more help.